# iOS How to enable Entitlements in Xcode 4.2 if I don't have a developer account

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, jailbreak, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I want to learn iOS development first then buy a developer account. So I'm using a Jailbreak+AppSync+iOS 5.0.1 device for development.

Then, I want to add some lines below to Entitlements.plist but I can't find this file and of course I can't make it by myself.

```
<dict> 
    <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key> 
    <true/> 
</dict>
```

From the official document, I found I can see Entitlements.plist in the shell and I see it.

```
codesign -d --entitlements -xxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app
```

Then I think the Entitlements.plist file for this app must be somewhere. I just want to add some lines to it.

I also found some questions that said to enable Entitlements.plist, you should do it in Organizer/Provisioning Profiles. But that question is about iCloud. I don't need iCloud. So I want to ask, is there anyway to write to Entitlements.plist without a developer account?

[ADD]

If Xcode 4.2 or iOS 5 don't necessarily need a Entitlements.plist anymore. How can I add this entitlement (com.apple.springboard.launchapplications) to my application.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure how well Jailbreak questions are supported here. You might want to take a look at the up-and-coming [iOS Jailbreak Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @n0rville Thanks for your link. I jailbreak my device just for learning.

Comment: I buy a developer license just for learning... I may publish my apps at a later date, but I still buy the iOS Dev License to a) Support Apple b) Get the latest OS updates (iOS 6) c) Get Support from the Apple Developer Community. And this way, I don't need to do stuff like jail breaking...

Comment: @n0rville Alright. Actually I can't afford it for now. And I borrowed this iPod Touch 4gen from my classmates....I'll buy it.

Comment: I'm not advising you to buy. I'm just saying that even though I couldn't exactly afford it, I shelled out for it because it had a lot of advantages.

Comment: @n0rville, there's many, many reasons to jailbreak, aside from not wanting to pay Apple $100/year

Comment: @Nate for customization? I prefer safety and security over a few silly animations. But, I feel that this conversation is getting off topic ("other reasons for jail breaking" isn't relevant to the original question) and I think we should end it here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can do a lot of learning using the iOS Simulator, which comes for free with Xcode. Get started with that, then buy a developer program when you're off the ground and ready to build software for real devices.

Comment: @n0rville, [read this](http://thebigboss.org/why-jailbreak-iphone-4s-4-3-3gs) if you're still unclear what else jail breaking gets you.  I did't post my comment in response to the question.  I posted it in response to you.  There's far too many posts on SO that amount to equating jailbreak development to stealing software, trivializing it in an inflammatory way (as you did), or attempting to push jailbreak content off the site.  If you make such a comment, then I'm going to take the liberty to respond.

Comment: @rickster, For issues that are closely related to code-signing (as this is), working with the simulator won't do much to increase your understanding.

Comment: @rickster I think I'll pay for it :) Do you have any idea about my question. Do I really need a developer license to enable Entitlements? Does Entitlements only works when 'Code Signing' is enable?

Comment: @Nate Actually I'm using a real device(sorry apple I will pay for it). Can you give me some advice about this question? Do I really need a developer license to enable Entitlements? Does Entitlements only works when 'Code Signing' is enable?

Comment: @wyp, I don't know.  I have always had the $100 Apple Developer license, so I don't know the answer to that.  I too, would like to see your question answered, because it will help me for an entirely different reason.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.2, click your project, then TARGETS->project name->Summary, at then end of this page, check "Enable Entitlements", then you can see a file appear in your project.
It is no longer needed, but if you want to specify property in it, you can do in this way. :-)